# Simplify hotkeys.js function

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to simplify this code instead of having to repeat the same information?...

```
shortcut.add("b",function() {
    $(".show_hide").trigger('click');  
    },{
    'disable_in_input':true
});

shortcut.add("a",function() {
    $("#about").trigger('click');  
    },{
    'disable_in_input':true
});

shortcut.add("w",function() {
    $(".show_hide_header").trigger('click');  
    },{
    'disable_in_input':true
});

shortcut.add("r",function() {
    $(".show_hide_l").trigger('click'); 
       },{
    'disable_in_input':true 
});

shortcut.add("up",function() {
    $("#prev").trigger('click');   
       },{
    'disable_in_input':true
});

shortcut.add("down",function() {
    $("#next").trigger('click');   
       },{
    'disable_in_input':true
});
```

It is for keyboard shortcuts http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like a limitation of the plugin itself. You would have to either modify the plugin as long as its BSD License permits or implement your own keyboard handling routines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var selectors = {'b': '.show_hide', 'a': '#about', 'w': '.show_hide_handler' },
    i;

function shortcutListener(selector){
    return function(){
         $(selector).trigger('click');
    }
}

for ( i in selectors){
    shortcut.add(i, shortcutListener(selectors[i]), {'disable_in_input' : true});
}
```

Comment: Fixed a bug... Sorry for that.

Comment: Thank you! Do you happen to know how to add a `.class` to the anchor when it is activated? (and then fade out the effect a second later? Just to give feedback to the user that it has been selected)